Where Can I Find the Energy Profiler in Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1?
I'm trying to monitor the battery usage of my application in Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1, but I'm unable to locate the energy profiler.
When I open a profiler session, I only see options for CPU and MEMORY

I've also checked the "System Trace" but couldn't find anything related to energy profiling

Could anyone provide guidance on how to access the energy profiler or suggest what might be causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

While this solution may not be ideal, I resolved the issue by downgrading my Android Studio version to Giraffe (2022.3.1 Patch 4), and now the energy profiler is functioning as expected.

For Android studio lguana 2023.2.1,
Please select the "System trace" item in the CPU profiler and then click the Record button.
In a while, click the Stop button, and then a new window will pop up shown as below picture where you can find what you want.
The energy/power profiler

Doe this only work for Pixel 6 and above devices?

Profileable power rails feature is available in Android 10 (API level 29) and higher and on Pixel 6 and subsequent Pixel devices according to https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/power-profiler#power-rails
